# enviar email con nodemailer, nodejs

Tags: nodejs, typescript, nodemailer

estoy tratando de enviar un email para que el usuario pueda restablecer su contraseña, el problema es que nunca use nodemailer y no puedo hacer que el mail llegue al usuaario, siguiendo la documentacion de nodemailer logre hacer esto:

```
import nodeMailer from 'nodemailer'

// async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
export const main = async (data: any) => {
  // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
  // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
  let testAccount = await nodeMailer.createTestAccount();

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
      pass: testAccount.pass, // generated ethereal password
    }
  });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'demo@gmail.com', // sender address
    to: 'enzonavarro28@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
    text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
    html: `
    <h1>
      prueba 
    </h1>`, // html body
  });

  return info
}
```

al parecer sale todo bien, mostando el info por consola, despues de terminar el proceso me devuelve esto

```
{
  accepted: [ 'enzonavarro28@gmail.com' ],
  rejected: [],
  envelopeTime: 896,
  messageTime: 639,
  messageSize: 612,
  response: '250 Accepted [STATUS=new MSGID=X-JjXJDTBVgHTkcyX-JjYCwZJlh6C- 
  uXAAAAAXPnRSl0PJuIx6E3jQ7wBxQ]',
  envelope: {
    from: 'demo@gmail.com',
    to: [ 'enzonavarro28@gmail.com' ]
  },
  messageId: '<bd0d4345-0a24-ee06-df51-ba8bbde53111@gmail.com>'
}
```

como detinatario ingrese mi email para poder observar como llegaba, pero no llega a la bandeja de entrade, el proceso parece estar bien pero el correo nunca llega a destino.

Comment: Trata cambiando el valor del _host_ por 'gmail'

Comment: `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND gmail` eso me devuelve la consola

Comment: El problema no será por esto `let testAccount = await nodeMailer.createTestAccount();`, vaya que el servicio `ethereal` no lo este enviado realmente, que sea para entorno de prueba.

Comment: y como lo soluciono?

Comment: Con una cuenta real podrías usarla, aunque sea para testear.
Elimina `let testAccount = await nodeMailer.createTestAccount();` y añade las opciones correctas en `nodeMailer.createTransport`. A mi me funciona con una cuenta de outlook.

Comment: Como recomendación, evita colocar datos personales.

Comment: tranquilo, solamente se ve mi email, nada malo